# Calling a function by class file name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have the function

```
wstring trim(wstring& str)
{
  string::size_type pos = str.find_last_not_of(' ');
  if(pos != string::npos) {
    str.erase(pos + 1);
    pos = str.find_first_not_of(' ');
    if(pos != string::npos) str.erase(0, pos);
  }
  else str.erase(str.begin(), str.end());

  return str;
}
```

in the file strhelper.cpp.

I would like to ask if it is possible to call the function like this:

```
strhelper.trim(...
```

or

```
strhelper::trim(...
```

This would help me work faster. Currently when I type "trim", the VS IDE offers me many functions that I am not looking for.
If I could restrict the function name search to my file, VS would not offer so many undesired results, but I have not found a way to do that yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Completely unclear what you're actually asking for.

Comment: What is a "class file name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's kind of what *namespace* are for:

```
namespace strhelper
{
    wstring trim(wstring& str)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You also need to remember to put the function prototype in the namespace as well in your header file:

```
namespace strhelper
{
    wstring trim(wstring& str);
}
```

Comment: That works fine, but now I can not use the functions in that class without using strhelper:: anymore. Is that intended?

Comment: @MaikenRosk You can always do `using namespace strhelper;` to pull in the functions in it in the current scope, but then you might go back to the trouble you had from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the great hints!

Answer (score 0):

The latter is possible:

```
strhelper::trim(...
```

If you simply wrap the function declaration and definition in a namespace scope:

```
namespace strhelper {
    wstring trim(wstring& str){ /* your code here*/ }
}
```